# How can a gun fire immediately after swapping?

Tags: counter-strike-global-offensive

I was playing against a guy the other day who would have his knife out, use the knife crosshairs to aim, and then switch to an awp and immediately fire. Whenever I switch weapons there is always a delay for the animation before I can fire. Was I seeing some kind of exploit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either you played on a custom server where they really changed some parameters regarding the weapon switching or it was just an optical illusion.

There is something what is called *fast-* or *quickswitching*. You can find much about it in the web, but this video shows very well, that the actual time you need for usual switching is the same as you need for *quickswitching*.

Anyway it's a good strategy to switch weapon instantly after shooting (with AWP especially). While some players just want to keep "their hands busy", others want to switch to pistol directly in order to turn off the enemy with it, when the AWP shot missed.

Also found [this post: Things about CS:GO that you probably did not know](https://www.reddit.com/r/GlobalOffensive/comments/1y8pg0/things_about_cs_go_that_you_probably_didnt_know/). Next to quickswitching there are other interesting things explained.